# Kafka Confluent Client .NET Core Cannot Access the Windows Intermediate Certificate Authoroties

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, librdkafka

I had posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310003/when-enablesslcertificateverification-is-set-to-true-confluent-kafka-certifi) regarding setting the **EnableSslCertificateVerification** setting yo true how it doesn't work on Windows. SSL handshake fails.

I found out that this is solved by adding the **SslCaLocation** setting as follows:

```
"Dev-on-Windows": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Kafka__BootstrapServers": "myloadbalancer.myhost.corp:9094",
        "Kafka__EnableSslCertificateVerification": "true",
        "Kafka__SchemaRegistryUrl": "myschemareg.myhost.corp:8081,myschemreg2.myhost.corp:8081",
        "Kafka__SecurityProtocol": "SaslSsl",
        "Kafka__SslCaLocation": "cacert.pem",
        "Kafka__SaslMechanism": "Gssapi",       
        "Kafka__ClientId": "DotNetCoreReferenceApplication",
        "Kafka__ErrorTolerance": "Moderate",
        "Kafka__Debug" : "all",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
```

Where cacert.pem file is simply the concatenation of the signatures PKs of the certificates. That works.
I am not sure why that is needed when ideally it should be able to check the trusted root store on Windows.

**UPDATE**

Two certs are required. One of them is in the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities and the other is in the Intermediate Certificate Authorities.

I removed the **SslCaLocation** configuration and simply imported the second certificate from the Intermediate store to the Root store and it worked.

Does Confluent Client Lib for Kafka / librdkafka for Windows not look into the Intermediate Certificate Store?

Comment: just FYI there is bug in librdkafka which Confluent client relies on. On Windows, only the CAs in the Root CA store matters. the client does not enumerate the Intermediate CA store.

Comment: please see here: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/3025

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that the Certificate store was not configurable.
See: https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/issues/3025

The issue was resolved and it became configurable now as shown below.

We can try the configuration:
`ssl.windows.certificate.store=Intermediate,Root`
Which corresponds to the config in .NET Confluent Library as
`SslCaCertificateStores`

Answer (score 0):

The user from which you run the application must have read permissions for the private key.

[Cant get private key from certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343101/cant-get-private-key-from-certificate)

[image]