# Cant get private key from certificate

Tags: c#, .net-core

So, I having trouble to get the private key from the certificate. This is my first time working with certificates and I have tried to find a solution to this but I cant make i work. It's a console application and a need the key to sign a SOAP message/request.

Here is a code sample; (Let me know if you need anything more)

```
    public static X509Certificate2 FindCertificate(string issuedBy)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        //We gets the certificate from store
        var certificate = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Issuer.Contains($"CN={issuedBy}"));
        if (certificate.HasPrivateKey) // Result: True
        {
            //PrivateKey throws error: Keyset dosent exist
            var key = certificate.PrivateKey;

        }

        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Could not find certificate issued by: '{issuedBy}'", nameof(issuedBy));
        }

        var expireDate = DateTime.Parse(certificate.GetExpirationDateString());

        if (expireDate < DateTime.Now)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Certificate has already expired: '{expireDate}'");
        }

      

        return certificate;
    }
```

Comment: As per [tagging guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), please refrain from putting tags in your question titles.

Comment: Most likely, the Private keys are not exportable and/or your User Principal does not have permission to manage private keys on that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work now just by start Visual Studio in Admin mode.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to your own solution (so you don't have to run VS in administrator mode is to give your own user privileges to read the private key.

1. Open the certificate manager for your machine certificates (type in "certificates" in Windows home menu search and choose "Manage computer certificates"
2. Find the certificate and right click -> "All Tasks" -> "Manage Private Keys..."
   [image]
3. Click "Add..."
4. Type in your username (and click "Check Names" to see if you typed it in correctly)
   [image]
5. Click "OK" and "OK"

Now you should be able to run your application (and VS) normally with access to the private key.